# Generate a power multi-set from r elements that has size n

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I wish to generate a power multi-set from r elements that has size n.

Say the function is

```
public List<List<string>> PowerMultiSet (List<string> elems, int n )
```

Example
input: {"d1","d2",d3"}, n=2
output: {"d1","d1"}, {"d1","d2"},{"d1","d3"},{"d2","d2"}, {"d2","d3"},{"d3","d3"}
Say the size of elems is r, the number of elements generated are C(n+r-1,r-1).

I wonder how to achieve this without redundant operations (i.e. the number operations should be ideally = C(r+n-1,n-1))

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure whether I get you right: Isn't a `List< List < string > >` what you want? Don't you get n!/(n-k)! times k entries?

Comment: Your function prototype is in C#, do you want a C# or C++ solution? Pick one!

Comment: C# and C++ are both ok for me, prefer c#.
yes, it is  List < List<string> > sorry about that

Comment: why it is n!/(n-k)! times k entries?

Comment: This can be thing of distribute n identical balls into r distinct boxes which allowed empty boxes, therefore it has C(r+n-1,n-1)

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the variables, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code solves the problem:

```
void MultiSet(List<string> elems, int last, int n, ref List<string> set, ref List<List<string>> result)
{
    if (set.Count < n)
    {
        for (int index = last; index < elems.Count; index++)
        {
            set.Add(elems[index]);
            MultiSet(elems, index, n, ref set, ref result);
            set.RemoveAt(set.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(new List<string>(set));
    }
}

List<List<string>> PowerMultiSet(List<string> elems, int n)
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();
    var set = new List<string>();
    MultiSet(elems, 0, n, ref set, ref result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am using this solution at the end as it is faster.

Comment: did you know if an iterative solution can be arranged somehow? theoretically all recursive algorithms can be expressed as a lineal one :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in a recursive manner. Call the function below with an empty `start` to start the recursion.

```
public List<List<string>> PowerMultiSet (List<string> start, List<string> elems, int n )
{
    List<List<string>> output = new List<List<string>>();
    if (n > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elems.Count; i++)
        {
            start.Add(elems[i]);
            List<List<string>> current = PowerMultiSet(start, elems.GetRange(i, elems.Count - i), n - 1);
            start.RemoveAt(start.Count - 1);
            output.AddRange(current);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output.Add(new List<string>(start));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Example call:

```
List<string> elems = new List<string> { "d1", "d2", "d3"};
List<string> start = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> x = PowerMultiSet(start, elems, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the permutation problem, except the length of each of the permutations is already decided. To simplify, assume we're printing the sets and define the following recursive function:

```
public void PrintPowerMultiSets(List<string> elems, int index, List<string> ps, int num_left)
```

Where index is the index in elems of the element that we want to add to the powerset, ps is the currently built powerset in this branch, and num_left is the number of elements we can still add to ps. At each recursive call to this function, add elems[index] to ps and call PrintPowerMultiSets with num_left-1 for every element in elems that has an index <= the passed in index. Stop recursing once you don't have any more elements to add to that powerset and print it (or add it to some list).

All you need to start this off is to call this function once for each element in the list. If you work through it, I'm sure you'll find that this is the same way in which you enumerated the output in your original question manually.